# Not able to capture image while generating pdf using puppeteer API

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Node- v8.11.1  Headless Chrome
Im trying to generate PDF but somehow the background image is not captured in the PDF.
Below is the code. Any help is appreciated

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://54.201.139.151/', {waitUntil : 'networkidle0'});
await page.pdf({path: 'hn40.pdf', printBackground: true, width: '1024px' , height: '768px'});
await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: dont you need to `await page.emulateMedia('screen');` first? See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions

Comment: Thanks. This works

Comment: No worries, should have provided an answer, but was rushed for time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rippo mentioned, [you require](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) `page.emulateMedia("screen")` for this to work properly. I have updated your script below, but I changed the page to google for testing.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://google.ca/', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2'});
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.pdf({path: 'hn40.pdf', printBackground: true, width: '1024px' , height: '768px'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 8):

Update: `page.emulateMedia()` is dropped in favor of `page.emulateMediaType()`

Comment: Can you please give more context with your answer so it is more clear.